# 2002 Honda Civic over heating

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

so lately I’ve been struggling with my car over heating. It has been an on going fight for a year already. At first I changed my thermostat, that seemed to help for a while then it began over heating again so I added anti freeze. For sometime I had to keep adding anti freeze every 2-3 days. So I went ahead and changed my radiator, I changed it because when my car would over heat I would see whiteish celarían smoke coming out from like the front of my car. And during this whole time my fans would turn on. So just this past week it’s been over heating again and now this time my fan isn’t turning on. So I changed the sensor to my car and again no fans are turning on and now I can’t run the car for more than 15 mins without it completely wanting to over heat. When I notice it over heating I turn on the heater and it’ll come back down right away but not all the time.. is there anyone who might know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check the water pump - some look ok from the outside but the impeller separates from the shaft internally so it does not force the water around and relying on thermosyphon flow is not sufficient for the engine but may well be sufficient for heating.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your radiator is clogged,if you let your car idle for a few minutes does the hoses on the radiator get warm both the top and bottom hoses.

You need to let the engine warm up to feel if the lower radiator hose gets warm,if it stays cool the radiator is clogged and needs to be replaced.

The temparature sensor for the cooling fan is often placed in the radiator but if the radiator is clogged the radiator stay cool so the fan does not start.

You say the heater functions so the water pump is functioning and cooling fluid is circulating.

If the radiator cap does not close as it should the boiling point of the coolant will be too low so you might try to change this to a new one,over time the spring in the radiator cap will loose some of its tension this might lead to the coolant boiling as the cooling system works with above atmospheric pressure.

Please take a look at the engine oil is this grey or white your head gasket is blown.if it looks dark brown your head gasket is ok,a blown head gasket might be expensive for you.

Comment: The OP says that the radiator has already been changed.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry i did not see that.